# Android Studio не видит классы

Tags: java, android, android-studio

После отключения электричества Android Studio перестал воспринимать какие-либо импортируемые классы. Теперь весь мой проект выглядит вот так: [image: скрин]

Перезагрузка студии не помогла. Подскажите, что делать

Comment: Проверьте настройки студии - может у вас слетел путь к SDK или к Java

Comment: @emptybottle или удалите папку .gradle в папке проекта при закрытой Android Studio  и заново откройте проект в ней...

Comment: clean/rebuild по идее должен помочь

Comment: Иногда проблема в кэше. Попробуйте File->Invalidate caches. Потом сделайте ребилд и синхронизируйте gradle, если Вы его используете конечно...

Comment: справа панель Gradle в ней иконка обновления. попробуйте ее

Answer (score 1):

Очевидно, слетела настройка Android SDK - [откройте настройки модуля](http://chrisrisner.com/Changing-the-SDK-Path-with-Android-Studio) и убедитесь, что путь до Android SDK правильный.

Если путь верный, значит слетели кеши Intellij. [Почистите кеши](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/cleaning-system-cache.html) с помощью **File | Invalidate caches (Restart)**

Если и это не помогает, лучше скачать последний билд Android Studio и открыть проект им.